# SQL 2 HAVING syntax

Tags: sql

My professor is teaching sql 2, and used an statement like the code below into a query:

```
HAVING SUM(column) > subselect
```

Where `subselect` is something like `SELECT AVG(column) FROM ...`

This subselect returns only one value, but I could not understand how is it possible to compare a function (the `sum`) with a subselect. The subselect should return a table, right? Then how is it possible to compare a table with a value? That did not make sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A subselect either return a "table" as you call which is in fact a set of values defined by fields OR one value **IF** the subselect has only one column and returns only one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL has a concept of *scalar subqueries*.  These are subqueries that return exactly one column and at most one row.  Scalar subqueries can be used in almost all cases where a single value ("scalar") can be used.

If the scalar subquery returns no rows, then the value is treated as `NULL`.

(I should add that some databases support *tuples*.  A tuple is a set of scalar values that is treated as a single value.  In such databases "scalar" subqueries can return more than one value, but these are converted to a tuple.  This is not relevant to the question being asked; tuples are just another example of a "single" value.)

Answer (score 1):

In principle you are right, if you look at it in a relational way.
But SQL is an industry standard and allows the abbreviation of comparing a scalar value with a result table with only a single row and column.

Depending on the exact implementation, it even allows to compare a scalar with a list of values (a column with more than one value), although you actually should write `... value > ALL (subselect)`, it is often accepted without the ALL keyword.

This is both valid syntax in the where and in the having clause